# Is it ok to pad a washing machine against the adjacent cabinetry?

Tags: kitchens, appliances, kitchen-counters

Not sure how to explain this.. have a new wash machine and it has to go under a counter in small space. The floor is in terrible condition (rotting old plyboard and cork), uneven and falling to bits, so did my best to level the machine. But it was still vibrating on spin.

So i just put some old dvd boxes between the sides of the machine and the counters next to it, effectively packing it in super tight.

Now it doesn't vibrate, even though its not perfectly level.

Question is, is this bad for the machine? Are they supposed to be allowed to vibrate their casing a bit? Or is it ok? Thanks. It's a magnetic drive bosch btw.

Answer (score 2):

I assume this is a front-loader? Front loaders spin at incredibly high speeds and pretty much require a very solid floor. So for sure, your floor isn't helping things.

That said, short of a concrete slab, most people don't have the 'solid' floor truly required. Even a well built wood floor on floor joists can have enough 'bounce' to it to wreak havoc when front loaders are running.

As such, it's actually common for people to 'pad' their washers. A common solution is to use pool noodles--those large foam tubes kids use in the polls. Wedge those between your wall/cabinet and the washer.

I avoid front loaders for this reason (as well as the cleaning issues) and now prefer high efficiency top loaders. But even they can vibrate. With my most recent install, I wedged strips of pipe insulation (basically smaller versions of the pool noodles) between the washer and dryer and between those and the wall. I took it a step further and also wedged strips in vertically along the front as well as strips cut in half along the bottom. Not only does this greatly reduce vibrations...but now we no longer have to deal with socks falling in between and/or under the washer and dryer.

Answer (score 1):

We had a washing machine vibrate violently when we tested it for the first time. 
It turned out that it had these shipping bolts that was securing the drum. When we removed them the vibration stopped.

Check to see if youe machine has any shipping protection in place. If so follow the instructions to remove them.

Comment: i took them out. Have installed quite a few in my time, but where i live now just has the sub optimal conditions with the floor and space available.